# Find tiny url final redirected url

Tags: python, redirect, tinyurl

I have followed several other questions in SO to find the final redirect url, however for the following url I can't make the redirect work. It doesn't redirect and stays at tinyurl.

```
import urllib2
def getFinalUrl(start_url):
        var = urllib2.urlopen(start_url)
        final_url = var.geturl()
        return final_url


url = "http://redirect.tinyurl.com/api/click?key=a7e37b5f6ff1de9cb410158b1013e54a&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fprofile%2FA3B4EO22KUPKYW&loc=&cuid=0072ce987ebb47328d22e465a051ce7&opt=false&format=txt"
redirect = getFinalUrl(url)
print "redirect: " + redirect
```

the result (which is not the final url if you try in a browser):

```
redirect: http://redirect.tinyurl.com/api/click?key=a7e37b5f6ff1de9cb410158b1013e54a&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fprofile%2FA3B4EO22KUPKYW&loc=&cuid=0072ce987ebb47328d22e465a051ce7&opt=false&format=txt
```

Comment: your url already has destination url....

Comment: You need javascript to redirect, print  the html returned and you will see We *can't automatically redirect you because JavaScript isn't available.*

Comment: @taesu if you try it in a browser it will get redirected.

Comment: What I mean is you don't have to send a get request to tinyurl.com, as you already have the destination url in YOUR URL

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the hint. Is it possible to fake having javascript somehow with scripting? Or do you mean I must use a browser (like selenium) to find these redirects?

Comment: @apadana, yes you will need something like selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://redirect.tinyurl.com/api/click?key=a7e37b5f6ff1de9cb410158b1013e54a&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fprofile%2FA3B4EO22KUPKYW&loc=&cuid=0072ce987ebb47328d22e465a051ce7&opt=false&format=txt'
try:
    out = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)['out'][0]
    print(out) #http://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/A3B4EO22KUPKYW
except Exception as e: # dont catch all
    print('not found')
```

This kind of url does not need to be curled to find out what the destination/redirect url is, well, because you ALREADY have them in your url.

---

If the destination/redirect url is not shown like this guy

> tinyurl.com/xxxx

then that's a different story, you'd have to curl it to find out what it resolves/304 to like below:

```
import requests
url = 'http://urlshortener.com/applebanana'
t = requests.get(url)
print(t.url)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for this specific case, however I have a ton of redirect urls which I don't know whether it will come to tiny or not, so I am looking for a more generic solution, so that I don't need to parse the url. Anyway thanks for your answer. For now I can add a if condition to parse and find this url in this way. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: There is no generic way of solving problem, when your input is not consistent. It will have to detect the url pattern, and use the applicable function to solve.

Comment: If I use a browser with selenium I can consistently find the urls. The problem is with urllib2 that can't redirect. Somehow it detects that my request is not coming from a browser, and it gives an html error page in the response.

Comment: It's not that `urllib2` can't redirect,`urllib2` will only send a GET request.If you view-source your URL, then you will see that the redirect is performed by `js`, not 304 `header`. That's the reason why you can't use `urllib2`. If you wanna use `selenium` or `panthamjs` that's going to be more costly in terms of resouces for such simple task.